# C# Tcp Server not receiving packets

Tags: c#, windows, sockets, tcp, network-programming

Ok the problem is really hard to explain, but I'll try. I'm basically making a tcp based messaging program that uses a server and multiple clients. What's happening is I'm sending tcp packets to the server from the client and they are getting to the server computer but not the actual server program. The server is running on a Windows 7 Pro Desktop and the client is running on a Windows 8 Home Prem HP Laptop. It never even sees a client connecting. The weird thing is that it works perfectly when I run the server on the laptop and the client on the desktop. It also works perfectly with 2 Windows 8 Tablets. It doesn't work with a Windows 10 HP All-in-one as the server and a Windows 7 Desktop as the client. The Windows 10 all-in-one had an error in event viewer from Kernel-Base.dll when I tried to connect from the desktop but with the Windows 7 Desktop as server and laptop as client it doesn't show the error on the desktop or laptop. It also works when I have the server and client on the same computer using localhost, any computer. I also checked firewalls of all computers and they have all the ports allowed and working. The problem is not connecting the two but it's why windows isn't forwarding the packets to the server program.

Server Packet Handling Code:

```
private void ListenForClients()
    {
      listener.Start();
      console.AppendText("Listening for clients.\n");
      console.AppendText("[SERVER STARTED SUCCESSFULLY]\n");
      serverInfoText.Text = "Server IP: " + getLocalIP();
      while (true)
      {
        TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();

        Thread clientThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(HandleClientComm));
        clientThread.Start(client);
        Thread.Sleep(10);
      }
    }

private void HandleClientComm(object client)
    {
        TcpClient tcpClient = (TcpClient)client;
        NetworkStream clientStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
        string sentMessage;

        byte[] message = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead;

        while (true) {
        bytesRead = 0;

        try
        {
          bytesRead = clientStream.Read(message, 0, 4096);
        }
        catch
        {
          break;
        }

        if (bytesRead == 0)
        {
          break;
        }
        clientStream.Write(message, 0, message.Length);
        ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
        sentMessage = encoder.GetString(message, 0, bytesRead);
```

The rest of that code is parsing messages and other things. Yeah, I said it's hard to explain but I'm extremely confused as to why this is doing what it's doing. Any help is appreciated, I've spent like 4 days trying to fix this. I also have the packet that it's not recieving (paste in here: http://sadjad.me/phd/):

```
0000   e0 3f 49 a6 6c 06 00 1e 33 ba bf 97 08 00 45 00
0010   00 34 50 74 40 00 80 06 28 f4 c0 a8 00 08 c0 a8
0020   00 03 c0 15 19 d0 f8 9b aa e0 00 00 00 00 80 02
0030   20 00 50 52 00 00 02 04 05 b4 01 03 03 08 01 01
0040   04 020 02 04 05 b4 01 03 03 08 01 01 04 02
```

Comment: firewall rules? make trebly sure that there is a hole in the firewall for this port over TCP; you could even disable the firewall **temporarily** to see if that makes it work, assuming the server is  relatively isolated

Comment: btw: thread per client is  *usually* not a good idea; it'll work for a small number of clients, though

Comment: This question is a repetition of the existing 100 questions that are like "my server does not receive connections". Prove that you checked all the common causes. Then, post minimal code reproducing the issue. Since no connection is incoming the function HandleClientComm is unnecessary to see. But we must how you start the server. Fix all of that and report back. Closing for now.

Comment: I'm guessing you know the packets arrived at the server using wireshark or similar? Note that wireshark can pick up packets before they hit the windows firewall.

Comment: Comment 1: Ok, I have checked the firewall 2 minutes ago and all the rules allowed the program through. Comment 2: I might think of fixing that later if I get problems. This is meant for LAN networks with a max users of like 20-50. Comment 3: I have checked around and looked at those but none have the same problems. If there is one that has the same I'll be happy to look at it if you send it to me. Comment 4: I am actually using Wireshark so I'll look into the firewall a bit more.

Comment: @Dom2364 as Marc suggested I'd try disabling the firewall completely (by stopping the base filtering engine service). If it works you know it was the fire and you can look deeper. If it doesn't you know it wasn't and you can forget about it for now

Comment: Have you checked if there is another program listening on that port. Try changing the port

Comment: Could you please post the implementation of the Sender?